# How to redirect new users to the page they came from after sign up (Next-auth)?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

My website has two main pages. (say `/profile/[nickname]` and `/products/[nickname]`)

I use single sign on with next-auth, and has two different pages for a new user to complete sign up:

1. Users need to sign in using Google ID ('Sign in with Google ID to continue', triggered by `signIn("google")`)
2. My website's `/signup` page, where they choose their nickname and agree to terms and conditions

Whenever a user clicks on a link or a button(e.g. comment box), I want to make sure the user has signed up.

This requires me to support four scenarios:

1. User has already signed up & is signed in: links/buttons works just as intended in this case
2. User has already signed up but is not signed in: redirect after sign in
3. User is signed in but has not signed up (has no nickname): clicking on links/buttons will take them to `/signup` page, but on the signup form submit, they will be redirected to the links they clicked on. If they clicked on 'Sign in' button, they should come back to where they were after signing up.
4. User is not signed in and has not signed up: similar to scenario 3, but clicking on links/buttons will first take them to 'Sign in with Google' page

I have two problems:

a. upon signIn, redirect to /signup if no nickname

b. upon signup form submission, redirect to whatever page they were trying to go (or do whatever action they were trying to perform), or if they just clicked on 'signin' button, come back to wherever they were.

For `a`, I have tried [signin callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#sign-in-callback) with `user.nickname` check. However, I'm not supposed to use it this way and session object is not even available on signup page. I'm also looking at [redirect callbacks](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#redirect-callback) but it doesn't seem like I can access the session object there either.

For `b`, if it's simple like scenario 2 from above, I can pass `{callbackUrl: ...}` but for 3 and 4, I think I need something more than that. I'm not super familiar but I remember there was a way to achieve this? Maybe I can save the page history in `sessionStorage` and then retrieve it in /signup? (I wasn't able to accomplish this using Next router)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you find any way to do so ?

Comment: @David not really

Answer (score 0):

For a. upon signIn, redirect to /signup if no nickname
You can set `redirect: false` in Next-Auth `signIn()` function, so that the page does not refresh, then you can write you own logic to redirect the user to whatever page you want, the reason we do this is because if you don't set redirect to false, you can use callBackUrl but it has to be an absolute URL; it cannot be dynamic.

Here is a similar snipet of my code

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const router = useRouter();

export default function SignIn() {
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = values;
    const response = await signIn('credentials', {
      email,
      password,
      redirect: false,
    });

    if (response.status === 200) router.back();

    console.log('incorrect user');
  };
```

Notice above I used `router.back()` to go to the previous page before user goes to my `/signin` page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to solve the problem:

1. Create a single custom sign-in page that takes a redirect query-string. It is possible to route to the sign-in page from any other page where the user is required to be signed in, passing the original page as a redirect query-string.  Call the Nextauth, client-side, signIn method here with the callbackUrl set to the sign-in page itself and the original page as the redirect query-string.
2. In getServerSideProps of the sign-in page:
   a. Redirect immediately (on 1st sign-in page access) to the original page if the user is already signed in.
   b. Sign the user in and (on the subsequent Nextauth callback) redirect to the original page if the user exists.
   c. Sign the user in and (on the subsequent Nextauth callback) redirect to an signup/profile page if the user is new.
3. The original page must be passed on to the signup/profile page as a redirect query-string as well. The signup/profile page will route to the original page once the user has updated this profile.

The sign-up page will look something like this:

```
export default function SignIn({ providers }: { providers: Provider[] }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { redirect } = router.query as { redirect: string };

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<EmailFormData>();

  const {
    handleSubmit: handleSubmitCredentials,
    register: registerCredentials,
    formState: { errors: errorsCredentials },
  } = useForm<CredentialsFormData>();

  const providerSignIn = async (
    providerId: string,
    opt?: { email?: string; password?: string }
  ) => {
    try {
      const isLoadingToastId = toast.info('Please wait - signing you in...', {
        duration: Infinity,
      });
      const result =
        providerId === 'email'
          ? await signIn(providerId, {
              redirect: false,
              email: opt?.email,
              callbackUrl: `/sign-in?redirect=${redirect}`,
            })
          : providerId === 'credentials'
          ? await signIn(providerId, {
              redirect: false,
              email: opt?.email,
              password: opt?.password,
              callbackUrl: `/sign-in?redirect=${redirect}`,
            })
          : await signIn(providerId, {
              callbackUrl: `/sign-in?redirect=${redirect}`,
            });

      if (result?.error) {
        toast.error(result.error);
      } else if (result?.ok && providerId === 'email') {
        toast.info(
          <span>
            Thank you for waiting. Please go to the email we just sent you and
            click on the login link to complete your sign in.
          </span>,
          {
            duration: Infinity,
            id: isLoadingToastId,
          }
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      toast.remove();
      toast.error(errMsg(e), {
        duration: Infinity,
      });
    }
  };

  const submitEmailHandler = async ({ email }: EmailFormData) => {
    await providerSignIn('email', { email });
  };

  const submitCredentialsHandler = async ({
    email,
    password,
  }: CredentialsFormData) => {
    await providerSignIn('credentials', { email, password });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>login</title>
      </Head>
      <h1 className="mb-4 text-xl">Login</h1>
      {Object.values(providers).map(
        (provider) =>
          provider.id !== 'email' &&
          provider.id !== 'credentials' && (
            <div className="mx-auto max-w-screen-md" key={provider.name}>
              <button
                className="primary-button"
                onClick={() => providerSignIn(provider.id)}
              >
                Sign in with {provider.name}
              </button>
            </div>
          )
      )}
      <form
        className="mx-auto max-w-screen-md"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitEmailHandler)}
      >
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            {...register('email', {
              required: 'Please enter email',
              pattern: {
                value: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/i,
                message: 'Invalid email address',
              },
            })}
            className="w-full"
            id="email"
            autoFocus
          ></input>
          {errors.email && (
            <div className="text-red-500">{errors.email.message}</div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="mb-4 ">
          <button className="primary-button">Sign in with Email</button>
        </div>
      </form>

      <form
        className="mx-auto max-w-screen-md"
        onSubmit={handleSubmitCredentials(submitCredentialsHandler)}
      >
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            {...registerCredentials('email', {
              required: 'Please enter email',
              pattern: {
                value: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/i,
                message: 'Invalid email address',
              },
            })}
            className="w-full"
            id="email"
            autoFocus
          ></input>
          {errorsCredentials.email && (
            <div className="text-red-500">
              {errorsCredentials.email.message}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            {...registerCredentials('password', {
              required: 'Please enter password',
            })}
            className="w-full"
            id="password"
            autoFocus
          ></input>
          {errorsCredentials.password && (
            <div className="text-red-500">
              {errorsCredentials.password.message}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4 ">
          <button className="primary-button">Sign in with Credentials</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const session = await getServerAuthSession(context);

  if (session) {
    const { redirect } = context.query as { redirect: string };
    const roles = session.user?.roles;
    if (!roles || roles.length === 0) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: `/profile?redirect=${redirect}`,
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
    }

    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: redirect || '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  return { props: { providers: await getProviders() } };
};
```